# Event id 5214 only in imported content database

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

only in attached content databases i see this error.
the permission on proc_UpdateDatabaseDefaultOptions are not linked to any sharepoint application role

the farm is version     16.0.10394.20021

any suggestion on how to resolve w/o explicitly granting db_owner role?

thanks

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          12/18/2023 12:00:05 AM
Event ID:      5214
Task Category: Database
Level:         Critical
Keywords:
User:          .sp19FST
Computer:      .nucmed.lan
Description:
Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: .sp19FST SID: S-1-5-21-766880239-1448664653-2215532624-27544 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in database 'WSS_Content__' on SQL Server instance 'sp19sqlinstance'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_UpdateDatabaseDefaultOptions', database 'WSS_Content__', schema 'dbo'.
Event Xml:



5214
16
1
3
0
0x2000000000000000

73492


Application
azwe-edmswfe01q.nucmed.lan

Comment: Did you check the permissions for the farm account? I think it should be owner of the content database. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-server-2016

Answer (score 0):

See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56634fbf-c6ec-486a-8643-7f4d424cf30d/event-id-5214-in-sharepoint-2013-environment

And: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/1402f3ad-0813-482d-b2f4-6565b21eba0d/sql-error-event-id-5214

That issue is because of insufficient SQL database permissions for the user in the 'WSS_Content__' database on your SQL Server instance 'sp19sqlinstance'. The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_UpdateDatabaseDefaultOptions', which is not linked to any SharePoint application role.

1. **Update Account Permissions:** In SharePoint’s Central Administration, update the permissions for the database access account.
2. **Adjust SQL Server Permissions:** In SQL Server Management Studio, change the permissions for the stored procedure ‘dbo.proc_GetProductVersions’.
3. **Update Search Service Account:** Give the search service account the necessary permissions in SharePoint.